# Are human-like characters shown in star wars humans?

Tags: star-wars, science-fiction-genre

The characters played by humans (eg.  Luke,  leia,  solo etc)  in star wars are Homo sapiens or any other species?  If they are homo sapiens then how could they exist in a galaxy far far away?  Did we reach there?  Or not homo sapiens then which species are they belonging to?

Comment: Coz if they are homo sapiens then how could they be in a galaxy far far away?

Comment: Parallel evolution. Or if you want, parallel creation.

Comment: See also [Are Anakin and Padme the same species?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92541/are-anakin-and-padme-the-same-species)

Comment: How could i know that my question is a duplicate one?  Even if i didn't duplicate it for my benefit?

Comment: The only way to know if it's a duplicate is to search for similar questions before posting your own.  It's not a perfect solution, of course, because there will be times when you simply don't find the duplicate before calling off the search.  Please don't be offended that the question was marked as such - it's not intended as an insult to you, it's just for site bookkeeping purposes.

Comment: Paying attention would be a good start; related/duplicate questions are shown to you as suggestions, as you type your question.