# Why did Padme marry Anakin?

Tags: star-wars

Anakin isn't really the most likable guy of all time. Padme had a lot of opportunity to see him go crazy, such as when he just went and murdered a bunch of sand people.

It seems... even a naive young woman who never dated might see this and other things as clear warning signs to not marry him.

Other than a plot device (if you can call it that... ?), are there any in universe reasons why she married him?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83170/what-attracted-padm%C3%A9-to-anakin?

Comment: "Love is blind"?

Comment: @HarryJohnston In this context, I think love is deaf

Comment: Love hired crappy writers.

Comment: Women wrote love letters to Joran Van Der Slooth (sp?) and Scott Peterson and Charles Manson? Someone married Stalin and Hitler and Pol Pot and Mao. This seems quite consistent with normal out of universe life.

Comment: @DVK Bingo. Chicks dig bad boys.

Comment: @Null - I'm gonna science the &^*t out of your comment: [Research #1](http://ink.library.smu.edu.sg/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=2215&context=soss_research) or [Research #2](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0191886913012245) </mark_watney>